# Website 'drupy' cannot be found

Tags: migrations

At our place it was decided to move away from PHP/Drupal (for bad or good) to a [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) based solution ([Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)). One thing we seriously consider is to do a gradual transition and for that I wanted to look at `drupy` that I have read about some time ago.

But the website www.drupy.com is some advertisement site now and googling *drupy* got me a lot of videos on youtube. Did this project get renamed? Where can I find information?

Is there some generic transition guide for gradual transition from Drupal?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! A Drupal port to Python is off-topic here since it is not Drupal and it is not PHP. Asking for a generic guide for gradual transition from Drupal is a too broad question, and it is off-topic. Eventually, we can answer questions about migrating to Drupal, but not questions about generic guides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project used to be on www.drupy.net (not .com), but that is an advertisement now as well.

The project was unfortunately discontinued (I like Drupal, but it is hard to move away from if you have to, and sometimes that is the better solution). The remainder can be [downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/brendoncrawford/drupy).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the maintainer left his domains to expire. The [GitHub repo](https://github.com/brendoncrawford/drupy/) is still up however.